# How do I arrange an ASP.NET Web API with authentication that is hosted on another subdomain?

Tags: web-api

Suppose I am designing a web application and also building a Web API with authentication via Kerberos/NTLM.  The Web API is first for my app, but I imagine I want to make it general-purpose.  My instinct is to create the Web API as its own separate solution, and then consume it with XHR requests in my web app.  So perhaps I have the API hosted at `fooapi.mysite.com`, and the browser-usable app is hosted at `foo.mysite.com`.

Should I thus enable CORS to allow for this?  Wouldn't I have to specify CORS origins for every consumer?  Or must I instead reproduce the API calls on my app, say under `foo.mysite.com/api`?  If the latter, is there a smart way to do so in ASP.NET without fully writing a second Web API?

Or do I have a wrong approach and I should stick to a application-specific Web API?

**What is common practice for the scenario of wanting to make an API mainly for one site but consumable by others too?**  Do I commit to CORS or do I need app-specific APIs?

Comment: There's something missing from your question, as it is already possible to use any ordinary Web API in any application, regardless of the domain.  Perhaps you really meant "a secured Web API," or "an API over SSL?"

Comment: Or perhaps you are running into cross-site javascript problems (aka CORS)?

Comment: Won't the browser block all CORS requests?

Comment: CORS stands for **C**ross-**O**rigin **R**esource **S**haring.  It specifies how you can make a cross-domain request *succeed,* not how you can block it.  Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Right. My understanding is that CORS is needed to allow for one site to call another's API, My question is should I do this, or do I need to make a site specific API instead? What is common practice for the scenario of wanting to make an API mainly for one site but consumable by others too?

Comment: I've edited the question title and content to be clearer.  This question is about the high-level architecture, but the difficulty that prompted it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900141/asp-net-core-cors-request-blocked-why-doesnt-my-api-apply-the-right-headers